# Prevent chat from auto-scrolling when message is sent in streamlit

Tags: python, html, frontend, streamlit

I am using streamlit v1.29.0 to create a chatbot interface. I am experiencing an annoying issue, where the page goes to the top of the page and then at the bottom right after a user sends a message. Strangely, this does not happen always, but just sometimes.

[Here is a gif showing my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJbc8.gif)